# Simulating a small world with Box2D

Tags: box2d, physics-engine

I would like to use Box2D to simulate a small world, with entity sizes around 1cm (0.01m), some smaller than that.

Box2D's FAQ says twice:

> Your moving objects should be between 0.1 - 10 meters.

> You should try to get your moving objects in the range 0.1 - 10 meters, with 1 meter being the sweet spot.

I cannot simply multiply all my numbers by 100, because the simulation would become unrealistic (very slow gravity etc).

Is it possible to simulate my world using Box2D?

---

I'm wondering for instance if it would be possible to scale all the numbers by 100 and transform all the forces and the velocities I apply to the bodies (including gravity) by some factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide to measure your game in cm instead of m.

So you'll take a 1.0 unit of distance inside your Box2D world and interpret it as 1.0 cm.

A velocity of 1.0 you'll then interpret as 1.0 \$\frac {cm} s\$ = 0.01 \$\frac m s\$.

A force of 1.0 you'll interpret as 1.0 \$\frac {kg \cdot cm} {s^2}\$ = 0.01 \$N\$.

To fix the "gravity too slow" problem, [set the gravity](https://box2d.org/documentation/classb2_world.html#aeafa43d6580e1dddb0675e672ca2375c) to -981 \$\frac {cm} {s^2}\$ (ie -9.81 m/s times 100 cm/m).

As long as you're consistent with how you're using and interpreting your numbers, this all works with non-meter scales. too. Meters are just the most conventional/intuitive option.

Comment: Thank you. Won't need to change anything about masses or other values? So, in short, every time I apply a force expressed in m/s (including gravity), impulse or set a velocity, I need to multiply those vectors by 100 to turn them in cm; and need to be aware that all the velocities and positions I read are in cm. That should be it. Correct? I was afraid it would be much more complicated.

Comment: For masses you'll want to either use measured kilogram values for the objects in question (ie. generally very small numbers), or compute a density value in \$\frac {kg} {cm^2}\$ if using masses generated from collider areas.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So far it seems like it's working! :)